# How to sort release version string in descending order with Bash

Tags: bash, sorting, sh

I have a list of release version strings that looks something like this:

```
releases=( "1.3.1243" "2.0.1231" "0.8.4454" "1.2.4124" "1.2.3231" "0.9.5231" )
```

How can I use bash to sort my `releases` array such that the array is sorted in descending order (so the value on the left has the highest precedence).

So the after sorting, the example above would be in the following order:

```
"2.0.1231", "1.3.1243", "1.2.4124", "1.2.3231", "0.9.5231", "0.8.4454"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually do it quite easily with *command substitution* and the version sort option to `sort`, e.g.

```
releases=($(printf "%s\n" "${releases[@]}" | sort -rV))
```

(**note:** the *printf-trick* simply separates the elements on separate lines so they can be piped to `sort` for sorting. `printf "%s\n"`, despite having only one `"%s"` conversion specifier, will process all input)

Now `releases` contains:

```
releases=("2.0.1231" "1.3.1243" "1.2.4124" "1.2.3231" "0.9.5231" "0.8.4454")
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
releases=( "1.3.1243" "2.0.1231" "0.8.4454" "1.2.4124" "1.2.3231" "0.9.5231" )
sorted=( $(echo ${releases[*]} | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sort -t. -k1,1rn -k2,2rn -k3,3rn) )
echo ${sorted[*]}
```

This uses `sed` and `sort` to reverse sort the items, using `.` as the field separator, and treating each field as numeric:

```sh
2.0.1231 1.3.1243 1.2.4124 1.2.3231 0.9.5231 0.8.4454
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
releases=( "1.3.1243" "2.0.1231" "0.8.4454" "1.2.4124" "1.2.3231" "0.9.5231"
readarray -t sorted < <(printf '%s\n' "${releases[@]}" | sort -Vr)
declare -p sorted
```

```
declare -a sorted=([0]="2.0.1231" [1]="1.3.1243" [2]="1.2.4124" [3]="1.2.3231" [4]="0.9.5231" [5]="0.8.4454")
```

Answer (score 0):

In Git, the version numbers are usually set using tags.

The following command will list the tags and sort them in descending order (with the flag -r)

```
git tag | sort -rV
```

The flag 'V' which stands for 'natural sort of (version) numbers within text is necessary for 'v10.0' to be on top of 'v9.0'.

To extract the last version number, use the following command:

```
git tag | sort -rV | head -n 1
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**